# Output caching и кэширование на уровне Jit компиляции

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, я возможно сейчас один глупый вопрос задам, но все же:

Мне не совсем понятно за счет чего страница закэшированная на уровне контроллера(OutputCache) должна обрабатываться быстрее , чем любая другая страница по дефолту кэшируемая Jit компилятором.По поводу этого в одной книге было следующее:

```
[OutputCache] is actually implemented using the core ASP.NET platform’s output-caching
technology, which means that if there’s a cache entry for a particular URL, it will be served without invoking any part of ASP.NET MVC
```

Но разве кеш Jit компилятора это не уровень веб-сервера?И все запросы, кроме первого , должны быть так же обработаны напрямую, не затрагивая ASP.NET MVC.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить два механизма, работающих на абсолютно разных уровнях:

1. JIT-компилятор выполняет компиляцию IL-кода при первом обращении приложения к этому коду. После этой операции он сохраняет скомпилированный код в памяти, чтобы не выполнять компиляцию при повторном обращении. Это верно не только для `ASP.NET` Web-приложений, но и для всех `.NET`-приложений (если они не были заранее скомпилированы в `native code`, например с помощью [`NGen`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngen)).
2. Атрибут `OutputCache` обеспечивает кэширование всех, либо некоторых действий контроллера. Это значит, что после первого обращения приложения к действию контроллера, результат этого действия будет закеширован, согласно параметрам атрибута. По умолчанию, он будет сохранен на Web-сервере, всех proxy-серверах (если таковые имеются) и в браузере пользователя. При последующих обращениях приложения к этому действию, оно не будет вызываться, а Web-сервер будет сразу возвращать результат из своего кэша. Такое кэширование (как вы указали в вопросе) реализовано платформой `ASP.NET` и характерно именно для Web-приложений.

**Отсюда и ответ на ваш вопрос:** ВЕСЬ код приложения компилируется по мере обращения к нему и сохраняется JIT-компилятором. Но это всего лишь *код*. Атрибут `OutputCache` обеспечивает кэширование *результата выполнения этого кода*, за счет чего код не будет вызываться повторно. Поэтому, при использовании `[OutputCache]` и достигается выигрыш в скорости.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую на свой вопрос что ли ответить:

Кэш Jit-компилятора хранит IL сборку (результат первого этапа компиляции) 
(.net исходник -> IL assembly)

Кэш [OutputCache] атрибута это готовый HTML, который не меняется определенное время (результат второго этапа компиляции)  (IL assembly + .aspx/.cshtml views -> html page)

Вроде так, если ничего не напутал. Т.е при jit компиляции CLR среда вроде как затрагивается.